# How to make Toffoli gate using matrix form in multi qubits system?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I wonder that there is generalized form to make Toffoli gate in multi-qubits system even if the two control qubits and one target qubit are not adjacent. In Wikipedia there is one way to make Toffoli gate with Hadamard, T gate and CNOTs, but I want to know how to make it for any case (i.e generalized version).

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by a generalised way?

Comment: If control qubits are 1st,2nd and target qubit is 4th then how I can make toffoli gate in matrix form?

Comment: are you asking how to find the matrix representation of a Toffoli between an arbitrary triple of qubits, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix form of a Toffoli gate with control qubits $q_a$ and $q_b$ and a target qubit $q_x$ applied on a $n$-sized qubit register may be described as
$$
T = \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc} 
t_{1,1} &  & \cdots & & t_{1,2^n}\\
 & \ddots & & \\
\vdots & & t_{i,j} & &  \vdots \\
& & & \ddots & \\
t_{2^n,1} & & \cdots & &  t_{2^n,2^n} 
\end{array} \right]
$$
with $t_{i,j} \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$ defined by

$$
t_{i,j} = \left \{ \begin{array}{rlcl}
  1  & \mbox{if } (i-1) \land M \neq M & { and } & j = i \\
1  & \mbox{if } (i-1) \land M = M & { and } & j = \delta_i + i \\
 0  & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array} \right. 
$$
where $\land$ represents the bitwise AND operator, $M = 2^{n-a} + 2^{n-b}$ and
$$
\delta_i = \left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
 (2^{n-x})  & \mbox{if } 2^{n-x} \land (i-1) = 0 \\ 
-(2^{n-x})  & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array} \right. 
$$
The matrix $T$ is an identiy matrix with some rows/cols switched to implement the controlled NOT gate: $M$ represents the mask used to identify the rows to be remapped and $\delta_i$ represents the shift applied to remap them.

I have prepared a short pyhton code snippet to calulate $T$

```
import numpy as np
def T(n,a,b,x) :
    m = 2**(n-a)+2**(n-b)
    d = lambda i : 2**(n-x) if (2**(n-x)) & i == 0 else -(2**(n-x))
    T = np.array([([0] * 2**n)] * 2**n)
    for i in range(2**n) :
        for j in range(2**n) :
            T[i][j] = 1 if (i & m == m and j == d(i) + i) or (i & m != m and j == i) else 0
    return T
```

For example, the Toffoli matrix T(4,3,2,1) is

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the OP's question is that there is some restriction imposed that a gates can only act on Adjacent Qubits. While this isn't necessary, we can still work with this restriction using SWAP gates to make non-adjacent qubit adjacent.

If the Control qubits are $i$ and $j$; and target qubit is $k$. Such that $i+1<j$ and $j+1<k$. Then we can use SWAP gates to bring these qubits closer.

If there is a distance between $i$ and $j$ i.e $j-i-1>0$, then we can use $j-i-1$ SWAP gates to bring the states of these qubits closer and apply the gate. Then another $j-i-1$ SWAP gate can be used to transfer the state back to its original position. This system is described for 2 qubits but can work for 3 qubits in case of a Toffoli Gate.

**Example**: We have 7 qubits $q_i$, $i\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We need to apply a $Toffoli$ Gate to $q_5$ with $q_0$ and $q_3$ as control.

Then the original state of the system is $q_0q_1q_2q_3q_4q_5q_6$.

We can apply the $CCNOT$ gate as follows

1. We apply SWAP gate to $q_0$ and $q_1$ resulting in state $q_1q_0q_2q_3q_4q_5q_6$.
2. We apply SWAP gate to $q_0$ and $q_2$ resulting in state $q_1q_2q_0q_3q_4q_5q_6$.
3. We apply SWAP gate to $q_4$ and $q_5$ resulting in state $q_1q_2q_0q_3q_5q_4q_6$.
4. We apply CCNOT gate on $q_0,q_3,q_5$ and now $q_5 \rightarrow q_5' $ resulting in state $q_1q_2q_0q_3q_5'q_4q_6$.
5. We apply SWAP gate to $q_5'$ and $q_4$ resulting in state $q_1q_2q_0q_3q_4q_5'q_6$.
6. We apply SWAP gate to $q_0$ and $q_2$ resulting in state $q_1q_0q_2q_3q_4q_5'q_6$.
7. We apply SWAP gate to $q_0$ and $q_1$ resulting in state $q_0q_1q_2q_3q_4q_5'q_6$.

In this manner you can apply $CCNOT$ gate to non-adjacent qubits using $SWAP$ gates.

**Note**: Just to be clear SWAP gates do not switch qubits but they are *unitaries* whose effect is that the state of the 2 qubits is swapped.
To know more about SWAP Gates see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Swap_(SWAP)_gate)